# How can I duplicate element of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do the following. For example with list comprehension.

Consider a simple list :

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

I want to duplicate each elements `n` times. Thus I did the following :

```
n = 3
duplic = list()
for li in l:
    duplic += [li for i in range(n)]
```

At the end duplic is :

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
n=3
duplic = [ li  for li in l for i in range(n)]
```

Everytime in python that you write

```
duplic = list()
for li in l:
    duplic +=
```

there is a good chance that it can be done with a list comprehension.

Comment: Just the simplest way !

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
duplic = [li for li in l for _ in range(n)]
```

This does the same as your code. It adds each element of `l` (`li for li in l`) n times (`for _ in range n`).

Comment: Can you explain the underscore role ?

Comment: @Ger The underscore is an unused variable. It's used when you want to ignore a value. It can also have [other meanings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python) in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
print sorted(l * 3)
```

Output:

> ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']

Comment: This ones actually elegant!

Comment: But what if original list goes not in sorted order? So `sorted` function will mess up everything.

Comment: also impractical for huge lists

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

n = 4

 >>>list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: [x]*n,l)))

['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

Comment: @RobertMoskal map and itertools are faster than list comprehensions.  Less readability, but more performance.

Comment: No arguments. If you are used to the idiom it's no big deal. But if you are used to programming imperatively, you have to run to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: l
Out[12]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

In [13]: n
Out[13]: 3

In [14]: sum((n*[item] for item in l), [])
Out[14]: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```